# Resuming video on phone after disconnecting from chromecast in CastVideos-android

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

I'm currently playing with the great sample application **CastVideos-android**, but can't get it to resume video playback on phone after disconnecting from Cast device.

I see this functionality prepared in *LocalPlayerActivity.java* with comment

> this will be the case only if we are coming from the
>   CastControllerActivity by disconnecting from a device

but it's never called (mShouldStartPlayback is always false).

Is there a simple way how to get it working? I'd be thankful for any pointers on where to start.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That feature is not there in that sample due to the structure of the app. For example, you are casting Movie A, then you go back and start browsing and click on Movie B to go to the detail page for that movie. Now Movie A is casting and you are looking at Movie B's detail page. If you disconnect at that time, should it replace the Video B with the Movie A and resume that? That won't be the best user experience. Due to the way the app is structured, that is not implemented.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Ali! Yes, it makes sense.
Could you please give me pointers on how to implement it anyway? For example getting position and url from receiver when disconnecting. I can't find the appropriate method. I can try implementing it only if user is browsing the same movie that is playing currently.

Comment: If you are using CCL, at each point in time you can get the info about the remote media easily by calling methods such as VideoCastManager#getRemoteMediaInformation() or getRemoteMediaPlayer().getApproximateStreamPosition(). You basically need to register a VideoCastConsumer in the activity that you want to resumt ehe video and have that consumer override onRemoteMediaPlayerStatusUpdate() and cache the info as updates happen; then when user disconnects, you can look at the cached values for the media and stream position and do the local playback, etc.

Comment: Ali, thanks for your comment. I tried overriding onRemoteMediaPlayerStatusUpdated in VideoBrowserActivity.onCreate under `mCastConsumer = new VideoCastConsumerImpl()`, but it was never called, even though I see that updates are happening in debug:
`D/ccl_VideoCastManager﹕ [v1.14] onRemoteMediaPlayerStatusUpdated() reached`

Comment: Did you register your consumer with the VideoCastManager?

Comment: You are absolutely correct once again Ali, my castConsumer was being removed in onPause(). I moved it to onDestroy() and now it's working as expected. I have one last question - I'm calling addVideoCastConsumer() in onResume(), which happens multiple times in the lifecycle, but removing the consumer only in onDestroy(). Is that a correct approach, or should I think about moving addVideoCastConsumer to onCreate? Thank you for your brilliant help.

Comment: You can add and remove consumers in either "onStart() + onStop()" or "onResume() + onPause()". If you have multiple activities and you navigate between them, you need to make sure to register consumers when you enter a new activity if you have removed them from the previous activity. You might be better off if you simply use onStart() and onStop().